# How to pass a parameter from SHDocVw.InternetExplorer event to C# application

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, shdocvw

I'm using

`SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer()`

At some point I need to trigger an event in my C# application from Internet Explorer. I'm doing that like this:

```
 var eventObj = btn.GetType()
                .GetEvents()
                .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "HTMLElementEvents_Event_onclick");

            if (eventObj != null) 
                eventObj.AddEventHandler(btn, new HTMLElementEvents_onclickEventHandler(GenericDomEvent));
```

This works OK, but I need to pass some parameter with this event and I'm not able to figure out how to do that. May be there is a way to call C# method from Internet Explorer? Please advise.

Comment: The event cannot provide an arbitrary parameter.  Use a lambda expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of banging head against the wall I came up with a solution. I'm using different event:

```
  var eventObj = btn.GetType()
                .GetEvents()
                .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "HTMLElementEvents2_Event_onclick");

            if (eventObj != null) 
                eventObj.AddEventHandler(btn, new HTMLElementEvents2_onclickEventHandler(GenericDomEvent));
```

And here is the event handler:

```
    private bool GenericDomEvent(IHTMLEventObj e)
    {            
        var element = e.srcElement;
        var command = element.title;
        var param = element.innerText;
        //Do whatever you want...
    }
```

The idea of this solution is to put the data into DOM element and trigger click event. In C# app you are listening for click event and as soon as event raised you reading your data from the element. Probably not the most elegant solution, but it works!